# Testing ionic elements using UFT 12.02 in IE 11

Tags: ionic-framework, internet-explorer-11, hp-uft

I am rather new to using automated testing tools, and as a practical learning exercise, I have been trying to test a small web application using HP UFT 12.02(I updated to 12.51, but am now running into the same issue).  The web app was created using the Ionic mobile development framework.  I have run into a roadblock and haven't been able to find an answer or similar experience recorded anywhere.

I am not certain whether the problem I have is with UFT, the browser, or with the actual application itself.

I am using IE 11 to test the application.  The UFT plugin for Firefox has been disabled at our site, and Chrome is not supposed to be installed on our machines, so I may have some awkward technical constraints.

I've tried recording my actions, and the only success I've had is using the "Insight Recording" mode.  In order to make the test readable, I have to do a lot of manual inspection of the objects and renaming.  Unfortunately, it seems there is a limitation to what I can select or inspect using UFT's tools.

Using the Object Spy, it seems that I can only select top-level web elements, and for the most part, it seems to work OK.  But here is the blocker:

In the app, there is a form that contains a series of pop-up selectors that allow me to select a building, a floor, and a date to reserve a space on that building's floor.

[Selector Screen from office reservation application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/532wu.png)

In IE, if I click the first selector (the Site), nothing happens--regardless of whether I have pop-ups blocked or not.  I get the same result performing a manual test on any of those selectors outside of UFT.
If I perform a manual test in Firefox, I get an ion-alert object that contains a series of radio buttons and OK/Cancel

If I inspect the element with Object Spy, I get a "Web Element" that includes the entire contents of the 
This includes the form title, all the ion-select elements and labels, etc (way too long to include in this question).

[Object Spy view of the site selector object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fk1Gd.png)

Is it possible to select an individual element within the form without resorting to x,y coordinates on the screen or window?  If so, how?  I cannot guarantee who will be running the test in future, nor how their screen or browser dimensions will be set.

Comment: Welcome to SO... In order to help you we need more info... Could you post html source code, screenshot of app and object spy, etc...?

Comment: Thanks Manish.  The html source code is really sparse because of the JavaScript.  The DOM Explorer is where I can see the details I think you are looking for.  It is pretty long.

Comment: Pls share whatever you can to help understand the issue.

Comment: I upgraded to UFT 12.51, and the Firefox UFT plugin now seems to be working.  As IE 11 does not seem to be compatible with the Ionic web-application, I have abandoned testing using that browser.

Comment: Unless its mandatory, I hate to use IE. Chrome proved to be fastest for me...